# GWD Rectangle hover color doesn't change

Tags: html, css, google-web-designer, html5-animation

For work I need to make some HTML5 banners and they are almost done except for 1 thing.
I need to code a hover change in the following HTML5 banner.
When you hover over the button the background colour of the rectangle need to change from orange to black.

Class gwd-grp-1b38 / ID 'oranje'

But it doesn't work... Any idea how to fix this?

I tried multiple things, even removed the tap area but the colour still didn't change.
The text on the button is a svg file because the fonts aren't online fonts, this resulted in making the button like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="Google Web Designer 15.0.4.1108">
  <meta name="template" content="Banner 3.0.0">
  <meta name="environment" content="gwd-genericad">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="gwdpage_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="13" data-exports-type="gwd-page">
  <link href="gwdpagedeck_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="14" data-exports-type="gwd-pagedeck">
  <link href="gwdimage_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="17" data-exports-type="gwd-image">
  <link href="gwdtaparea_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="7" data-exports-type="gwd-taparea">
  <style id="gwd-lightbox-style">
    .gwd-lightbox {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <style id="gwd-text-style">
    p {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    h1 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    h2 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    h3 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .gwd-page-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .gwd-page-content {
      background-color: transparent;
      transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
      position: absolute;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .gwd-page-content * {
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .gwd-page-wrapper {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateZ(0px);
    }
    .gwd-page-size {
      width: 160px;
      height: 600px;
    }
    .gwd-rect-1ll0 {
      position: absolute;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 160px;
      height: 600px;
    }
    .gwd-image-13h3 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 135px;
      height: 32.96px;
      left: 13px;
      top: 506px;
    }
    .gwd-image-qwzt {
      position: absolute;
      width: 135px;
      height: 48.18px;
      left: 9px;
      top: 157px;
    }
    .gwd-input-k9vt {
      position: absolute;
      border: none;
      background-image: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      height: 18px;
      width: 100px;
      left: 40px;
      top: 513px;
    }
    .gwd-taparea-lspc {
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      left: 15px;
      height: 40px;
      top: 544px;
    }
    .gwd-image-1efh {
      position: absolute;
      left: 9px;
      top: 106px;
      width: 105px;
      height: 18.41px;
    }
    .gwd-p-16bb {
      position: absolute;
      font-family: Verdana;
      background-image: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: rgb(0, 66, 136);
      font-weight: bold;
      width: 314px;
      line-height: 0px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      height: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      top: 136px;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    input:focus::placeholder {
      color: transparent;
    }
    textarea:focus, input:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
    .gwd-image-1i3o {
      position: absolute;
      width: 160px;
      height: 600px;
      top: 0px;
      left: 1px;
    }
    .gwd-image-1xcr {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      height: 420px;
      top: 205px;
      left: 94px;
      transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    @keyframes gwd-gen-4bzbgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
      0% {
        transform: translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate3d(-130px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
    }
    #page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-4bzbgwdanimation {
      animation: 0.7s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running gwd-gen-4bzbgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes;
    }
    [data-gwd-group="button"] .gwd-grp-1b38.gwd-image-10ho {
      position: absolute;
      width: 120px;
      height: 29.29px;
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
    }
    [data-gwd-group="button"] .gwd-grp-1b38.gwd-rect-361w {
      position: absolute;
      width: 120px;
      height: 29.2857px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-image-source: none;
      border-image-width: 1;
      border-image-outset: 0;
      border-image-repeat: stretch;
      border-color: transparent;
      background-image: none;
      background-color: rgb(244, 123, 32);
      border-radius: 3px;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
    }
    .gwd-rect-361w:hover {
      transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    }
    [data-gwd-group="button"] {
      width: 120px;
      height: 29.2857px;
    }
    .gwd-div-ap9v {
      position: absolute;
      left: 20px;
      top: 550px;
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
    @keyframes gwd-gen-1e3ngwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
      0% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      18.1818% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      22.7273% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1613, 1.1613, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      27.2727% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      54.5455% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      59.0909% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1613, 1.1613, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      63.6364% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      90.9091% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      95.4545% {
        transform: scale3d(1.1613, 1.1613, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      96.5455% {
        transform: scale3d(1.099, 1.099, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
    }
    #page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-1e3ngwdanimation {
      animation: 5.5s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running gwd-gen-1e3ngwdanimation_gwd-keyframes;
    }
  </style>
  <script data-source="googbase_min.js" data-version="4" data-exports-type="googbase" src="googbase_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwd_webcomponents_v1_min.js" data-version="2" data-exports-type="gwd_webcomponents_v1" src="gwd_webcomponents_v1_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdpage_min.js" data-version="13" data-exports-type="gwd-page" src="gwdpage_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdpagedeck_min.js" data-version="14" data-exports-type="gwd-pagedeck" src="gwdpagedeck_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdimage_min.js" data-version="17" data-exports-type="gwd-image" src="gwdimage_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdtaparea_min.js" data-version="7" data-exports-type="gwd-taparea" src="gwdtaparea_min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../GWD/160x600/assets/get_variables.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.adcombi.getFeed(adcombi.feedUrl)
  </script>
  <script data-source="gwdgenericad_min.js" data-version="8" data-exports-type="gwd-genericad" src="gwdgenericad_min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="groups_runtime.min.1.0.js" gwd-groups-version="1.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="gwdid.min.1.0.js" gwd-gwdid-version="1.0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="support" src="gwd-events-support.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">
    gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action = function(event) {
      // GWD Predefined Function
      gwd.actions.gwdGenericad.exit('gwd-ad', 'https://www.kwik-fit.nl/apk.go?kenteken=%5Bkenteken%5D', true, 'page1');
    };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="registration">
    // Ondersteuningscode voor gebeurtenisverwerking in Google Web Designer
    // Dit scriptblok is automatisch gegenereerd. Bewerk dit niet.
    gwd.actions.events.registerEventHandlers = function(event) {
      gwd.actions.events.addHandler('gwd-taparea_1', 'action', gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action, false);
    };
    gwd.actions.events.deregisterEventHandlers = function(event) {
      gwd.actions.events.removeHandler('gwd-taparea_1', 'action', gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action, false);
    };
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", gwd.actions.events.registerEventHandlers);
    document.addEventListener("unload", gwd.actions.events.deregisterEventHandlers);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <template id="gwd-group-definitions">
    <div data-gwd-group-def="button" data-gwd-group-class="gwd-grp-1b38" style="display: none;">
      <svg data-gwd-shape="rectangle" class="gwd-rect-361w gwd-grp-1b38" data-gwd-grp-id="oranje"></svg>
      <gwd-image source="assets/button-text.svg" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-10ho gwd-grp-1b38" data-gwd-grp-id="button"></gwd-image>
    </div>
  </template>
  <gwd-genericad id="gwd-ad">
    <gwd-pagedeck class="gwd-page-container" id="pagedeck">
      <gwd-page id="page1" class="gwd-page-wrapper gwd-page-size gwd-lightbox" data-gwd-width="160px" data-gwd-height="600px">
        <div class="gwd-page-content gwd-page-size">
          <gwd-image id="Achtergrond_KF_HTML_Banners_APK_zonder_man-5" source="assets/Achtergrond KF HTML Banners APK zonder man-5.jpg" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-1i3o" data-gwd-tl-locked=""></gwd-image>
          <gwd-image id="Man" source="assets/Man.png" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-1xcr gwd-gen-4bzbgwdanimation" data-gwd-tl-locked=""></gwd-image>
          <gwd-image id="kenteken" source="assets/Assets-kenteken.svg" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-13h3" data-gwd-tl-locked=""></gwd-image>
          <gwd-image id="je-apk" source="assets/je-apk.svg" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-1efh" data-gwd-tl-locked=""></gwd-image>
          <p class="gwd-p-16bb" data-gwd-tl-locked="">Plaatsnaam?</p>
          <gwd-image id="altijd-snel-300-600" source="assets/Assets-altijd-snel-300-600.svg" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-qwzt" data-gwd-tl-locked=""></gwd-image>
          <svg data-gwd-shape="rectangle" class="gwd-rect-1ll0" data-gwd-tl-locked=""></svg>
          <div class="gwd-div-ap9v gwd-gen-1e3ngwdanimation" data-gwd-group="button" id="knop"></div>
          <gwd-taparea id="gwd-taparea_1" class="gwd-taparea-lspc" data-gwd-tl-locked=""></gwd-taparea>
          <input type="text" id="textfield" class="gwd-input-k9vt" placeholder="Jouw kenteken" style="text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;" data-gwd-tl-locked="">
        </div>
      </gwd-page>
    </gwd-pagedeck>
  </gwd-genericad>
  <script type="text/javascript" id="gwd-init-code">
    (function() {
      var gwdAd = document.getElementById('gwd-ad');

      /**
       * Handles the DOMContentLoaded event. The DOMContentLoaded event is
       * fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed.
       */
      function handleDomContentLoaded(event) {

      }

      /**
       * Handles the WebComponentsReady event. This event is fired when all
       * custom elements have been registered and upgraded.
       */
      function handleWebComponentsReady(event) {
        // Start the Ad lifecycle.
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            gwdAd.initAd();
          }, 1);
        });
      }

      /**
       * Handles the event that is dispatched after the Ad has been
       * initialized and before the default page of the Ad is shown.
       */
      function handleAdInitialized(event) {}

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
        handleDomContentLoaded, false);
      window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady',
        handleWebComponentsReady, false);
      window.addEventListener('adinitialized',
        handleAdInitialized, false);
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to se if there are any errors shown on the console? I have run the code as you have given it and get an undefined (what is window.adcombi??).

Comment: I shall check that idea, thx. adcombi is the name of the organisation that will set up the campaign

Comment: I couldn't find anything but I found a way around it. First I put a taparea above an svg file but the coding didn't work. Now I created the button via the button component in GWD and when I code CSS for that it does work the way I want :-)